# Creating a dynamic collection select rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1, cascadingdropdown

I have gone through N number of solutions for creating a dynamic dropdown in rails but nothing seems to work.

I have a typical state and city model and I do not want to use carmen.

Here is my model :-

Market.rb

```
class Market < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :state, :cities_attributes

    has_and_belongs_to_many :users

    has_many :cities, :dependent => :destroy

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :cities

    validates :state, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true

end
```

City.rb

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :city

    belongs_to :market

    has_and_belongs_to_many :users

end
```

in devise/registrations/new (I want the user to select the state and city at the time of signup itself)

```
%li
  =f.collection_select :city, Market.all,:id, :state, html_options = { :class => "custom_textarea"}
%li
 =render "devise/registrations/cities", :f => f
```

_cities.html.haml partial

```
-unless cities.blank?
    =f.collection_select( :city, @cities, :id, :cities)
```

registrations_controller.rb

```
def update_city_select
    @cities = City.where(:country_id => params[:id])
    render :partial => "cities", :locals => {:cities => @cities}
end
```

I want the city list to change once the user selects a state and be populated with relevant cities.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use ajax for this in your view which contains the state dropdown:

```
$("#stateDropdown").change(function(){
  $.get("controller/update_city_select.html?id="+$("#stateDropdown").val(), 
        function(data){ $("#cityDropdownDiv").html(data); } );
});
```

This calls your action, and substitutes the content of your div to the new dropdown for cities.

To your partial:

```
#cityDropdownDiv
    -unless @cities.blank?
        = collection_select( :market, :city, @cities, :id, :cities)
```

With this, you don't need to add the `:f => f` parameter when rendering the partial.

You should add an id (I am assuming "stateDropdown") to your dropdown in the html_option part.

Comment: I am getting this error You have a nil object when you didn't expect it! on this line =f.collection_select( :city, @cities, :id, :cities)

Comment: The problem is that you dont have the form in your city partial partial. You can use some workaround for that problem. I can provide one in an hour if you need it.

Comment: could you please look at it once again?

Comment: I corrected it a bit, now it should work. I tried it. If it still doesn't work please provide some more information about the problematic parts.

Comment: the problemetic part i think is jquery line  $.get("controller/update_city_select.html?id="+$("#stateDropdown").val(),

Comment: This seems another issue, than the previous. I updated the answer (last sentence). Does this way the ajax being executed?

Comment: thanks but how will the selected value get saved in the db as it does not seem to be part of the original form?

Comment: On submit, the client collects the data from the DOM, so it should be sent just like the other part. You need to make sure that the div is in the form part, and the rest is taken care of. By parameterizing the collection_select (first 2 argument) you specify the same format the rails is using, so in the end, you get these parmeters in the params hash as all the others. Print the hash value on the save action and check if it is contained or not.

Answer (score 1):

One more tutorial which was really helpfull and I guess will help anyone looking to implement dependent dropdown is http://www.petermac.com/rails-3-jquery-and-multi-select-dependencies/